# click function firing despite using off, probably causing the array issue too

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a Simon game and I think I'm rather close to the end (Yay!), I seem to be stuck with an issue though. After the player matches the first move of simon it moves to the next round the and array is populated with a second move. Then you can match the second move and that also iterates correctly. But I think it's firing a second time and then it's usually wrong and then makes the player array have one move as the last move instead of resetting.

How can I make sure the button presses only fire once and how to make the player array reset properly?

```
function playerInput(simon, player, j){
    while (j < simon.length)  
        {
            console.log(j);
            if(simon[j] === player[j])
            {
                console.log("player pressed the correct button");
                j++;
                // potentially not working off function
                $(".simon-button").off().on('click', function() {
                    // stops multiple executions
                });
                buttons(simon, j, player);
            }
            else
            {
                if(strict === true)
                {
                    reset();
                    return; 
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("player pressed the wrong button");
                    // seems to be screwing up here when it's wrong
                    // but not when used to reset player when it's right
                    player = [];
                    repeatMoves(player);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    if(j >= simon.length && simon.length < 20) 
        {
            j = 0;
            player = [];
            newMove(player);
        }
    else
    {
        alert("You win!!!");
        successSound.play();
        reset();
    }   
}

function buttons(simon, j, player){
    green.css('cursor', 'pointer');
    red.css('cursor', 'pointer');
    blue.css('cursor', 'pointer');
    yellow.css('cursor', 'pointer');
    $(".simon-button").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("green-button"))
            {
                player.push(greenPushed());
                playerInput(simon, player, j);
            }
        else if($(this).hasClass("red-button"))
            {
                player.push(redPushed());
                playerInput(simon, player, j);
            }
        else if($(this).hasClass("blue-button"))
            {
                player.push(bluePushed());
                playerInput(simon, player, j);
            }
        else if($(this).hasClass("yellow-button"))
            {
                player.push(yellowPushed());
                playerInput(simon, player, j);
            }
        console.log(player);
        console.log(simon);
    });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uoyg2jx9/1/

I forgot to mention, to make the fiddle work click on the empty button and then the start button.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't digested your code enough to understand what this is supposed to do, but it sure has a whiff of endless loop about it:

```
while (j < simon.length)  {
    if(simon[j] === player[j]) {
        // ...
        j++; // ok
        // ...
    } else {
        // nothing in this clause modifies j.  To infinity and beyond...
    }
}
```

There *is* an `i=0;` in there, with no previous mention of `i`, so perhaps that's the problem (though setting j to zero would still leave you in an endless loop.)  I suspect you want to break out of that while loop in the `else`, perhaps by setting `j == simon.length`, or by `return`ing after `repeatMoves()`.

Comment: thanks that actually helped a lot. Now its buggy but at least it runs to move 2-3.